# Prevent multiple form submission MVC Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using Actionlink and JQuery to submit a form. It is submitting the form every time when clicking the link. I want to submit the form only the first time(once). The code is -

```
@Html.ActionLink(Model.link, "DefaultRate", "DefaultRate", null, new { @class = "btnclick", onclick = "return false;" })

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.btnclick').click(function () {
                $(this).closest('form')[0].submit();
        });
    });                                              
</script>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Satpal, I am new in JQuery, how to do this, please can you give me an example

Comment: [jQuery.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

Comment: ^^^^ is better solution

Comment: And do not miss the `e` in `one`,

Comment: Hi, I tried but did not work, <script type="text/javascript">
                            $(document).ready(function () {
                                $('.btnclick').one("click", function (e) {
                                    $(this).closest('form')[0].submit();
                                });
                            });                                              
                        </script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This must work:

```
@Html.ActionLink(Model.link, "DefaultRate", "DefaultRate", null, new { @class = "btnclick"})

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
             var allow = true;
             $('.btnclick').click(function () {
                  if (allow){
                      $(this).closest('form')[0].submit();
                      allow = false;
                  }
                  else 
                      return false;    
             });
        });                                              
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want

```
                <script type="text/javascript">

                    $(document).ready(function () {

                        $('.btnclick').bind("click", function () {

                            $('.btnclick').unbind("click");

                            $(this).closest('form')[0].submit();

                        });
                    });         

                </script>
```